# Proof for “if n|(a-b) then n|(b-a).”

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For all integers $n$, $a$, and $b$, if $n\mid(a-b)$ then $n\mid (b-a)$.

I understand that $(a-b) = nk$ for some integer $k$ but where do I go from there?

Comment: Then $(b-a) = n(-k)$.

Comment: Recall, if $k$ is an integer then $-k$ is also an integer

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

$$b-a = -a + b = -(a-b)$$

Comment: That's a give away.

Answer (score 0):

$$(a-b)-(b-a)=2a-2b=2(a-b)$$ and so $$n\mid (a-b)\implies n\mid 2(a-b)=(a-b)-(b-a)$$ which then implies division into their difference(s).